# Eclipse How to create new run configuration with commands

Tags: eclipse, run-configuration, microprofile

I'm working on an Eclipse microprofile application, and I would like to create a run configuration that executes these 3 commands in order:

```
mvn clean package
mvn package
java -jar target/myApp.jar
```

How can I do this? I have this:

[image]

Where and how can I set what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that from the m2 plugin, you be able to accomplish the task of running multiple maven goals within a single run configuration.

However, as a workaround, you can add a batch file within your maven project directory with the following entries

```
call cls
%cd%
call mvn clean install
call java -jar target/myApp.jar
```

Running the above script can help you with running multiple maven commands in a synchronized manner.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create a ***Maven Build*** launch configuration **for each of the first two commands**. The **third** command (`java -jar target/myApp.jar`) can be done with an ***External Tools Configuration*** of the type ***Program***.

Then, create a ***Launch Group*** with all these three launch configurations.